# React hook state not change in recursion

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, closures

I have a recursion custom hook that triggers a setTimeout function for 3 `chances`, if `chances` reaches 0, it should stop recursion.

However when the code runs, the chances in the `setTimeout` remains = 3, and the recursion wouldn't stop at all.

I think it has to do with closure, but I was not able to figure out how it fix this. Please explain it to me.

Example
https://codesandbox.io/s/recursion-state-closures-30wuo?file=/src/App.js

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const DEFAULT_CHANCES = 3;

function useRecursion() {
  var [chances, setChances] = useState(DEFAULT_CHANCES);

  const resetChances = () => setChances(DEFAULT_CHANCES);

  const minusChancesRecursivly = () => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      setChances((prev) => --prev);

      if (chances > 0) {
        console.log(chances);
        minusChancesRecursivly();
      }
    }, 1000);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    minusChancesRecursivly();
    return () => setChances(DEFAULT_CHANCES);
  }, []);

  return [chances, resetChances];
}

export default function App() {
  const [chances, resetChances] = useRecursion();

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={resetChances}>Click</button>
      <h1>Chances: {chances}</h1>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a problem in your `minusChancesRecursivly` where you are accessing `chances` in the settimeout. The value of `chances` will stay the same all every time you call the function as the value when you called it. You can fix this by putting the code in the callback you are passing to the `setChances` where it receives the current value of the chances in your `prev` argument.

But better approach to this will be passing the current chances value to the function as argument like so

```js
  const minusChancesRecursivly = (chancesLeft) => {
    setChances(chancesLeft);

    if (chancesLeft > 0) {
      setTimeout(
        () => minusChancesRecursivly(chancesLeft - 1),
        1000
      );
    }
  };
```

and then calling it as follows

```js
minusChancesRecursivly(3);
```

This in my opinion results in much more clear code that's written in the same way independently on the technology. I mean - the same concept will work the same in other framework or language.

Modified code is here
https://codesandbox.io/s/recursion-state-closures-forked-jbfgo?file=/src/App.js

(I've also added prevention for the race conditions, so you stop the previous timeouts when clicking on the reset button.)

Answer (score 0):

Your code have one problem.

before you set new value you checked it

```
  setChances((prev) => --prev);

  if (chances > 0) {
    console.log(chances);
    minusChancesRecursivly();
  }
```

This must work

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const DEFAULT_CHANCES = 3;

function useRecursion() {
  var [chances, setChances] = useState(DEFAULT_CHANCES);

  const resetChances = () => setChances(DEFAULT_CHANCES);

  const minusChancesRecursivly = () => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      setChances((prev) => --prev);
    }, 1000);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (chances > 0) {
      minusChancesRecursivly();
    }
  }, [chances]);

  return [chances, resetChances];
}

export default function App() {
  const [chances, resetChances] = useRecursion();

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={resetChances}>Click</button>
      <h1>Chances: {chances}</h1>
    </div>
  );
}
```